# Get UID of current auth user in a onCreate trigger function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get the UID of the auth user who created the new document in the cloud trigger function for the onCreate event.

I couldn't find on the documentation website how to do this. However, it's documented in the source code of the 'firebase-functions' JavaScript library that this should be `context.auth.uid` as in the code below. However, the code below reports in the logs that `context.auth` is `undefined` when a document is added by an authenticated user.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const mytriggerFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('someCollection/{documentId}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    console.log("Current auth:", context.auth);
    return true
  })
```

Comment: The short answer is that you can't (and you never will be able to) get the auth'd user in the Firestore trigger. You will need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `context.auth` is present in [Callable Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that are are called from client side and not in background functions such as Firestore triggers.

---

If you are trying to get UID of user who added the document in Firestore then you must add the same in the document while creating. You can then secure this by using the following security rules:

```
match /someCollection/{documentId} {
  allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId;
}
```

Then you can read the contents of the created document using `snapshot`:

```
const data = snapshot.data();

console.log(`Document created by ${data.userId}`)
```

Comment: I'm sure it was called from the client side and yet it's undefined.  I mean the even is triggered by a user who created a new document from the client side

Comment: @Menas you can't call `firestore.document().onCreate()` from client **directly**. You might be adding the document from client side and then it's Firestore that triggers the function in background,.

Comment: I know that. My question is how can I identify the user who created the new document from within the trigger function?

Comment: @Menas i've updated my answer. You would have to add user's UID in the document then.

Comment: I have surely thought of this workaround but it's not acceptable in my use case

Comment: @Menas can you specify the reason in that case? You  can use a Callable Function directly, add the document and run all the processes the the background functions would have